# Don't use getPrototypeOf?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY) (approx. 31 minutes in), Crockford says they (speaking on behalf of the ECMAScript committee) recommend *not* using `Object.getPrototypeOf`. His explanation was that it wasn't really meant for the average developer but was meant for things like Caja, which may remove it from `Object` to prevent you from accessing it.

Crockford can sometimes be pretty opinionated in his views on how JS should be used (can't we all?), so I'm wondering if this is really the full recommendation of the ES committee or if it's just one of Crockford's personal opinions. Has anyone read any official statement warning against using `Object.getPrototypeOf`? It really sounds like a bummer to me :(, but I don't see any information on the MDN page warning against its use, and I would expect a notice to be there if it really was that bad of an idea.

Comment: I haven't got time to write a full answer just now, but a couple of things I've found: 1. `__proto__` is not *obviously* a huge security issue, but Brendan Eich was against adding it because [it's non-standard and exposes an unnecessary attack surface](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2007-September/004556.html) (Mario Heiderich expands a little upon the security implications in his [doctoral thesis](http://heideri.ch/thesis)); and 2. Douglas first made this claim in definitive terms [back in 2008](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-July/006669.html).

Comment: This question is argumentative and will mainly provide opinionated answers. There's not right/wrong here. Although valid concerns but I should be formulated differently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

His reasoning there is incredibly poor. It (and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`) were not simply added for the use of Caja and similar. Nor does Caja simply delete them! Caja intercepts `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` in order to implement `WeakMap` (which [my shim](https://github.com/Benvie/harmony-collections) does as well) and as far as I can tell it doesn't modify getPrototypeOf. In reality it would be pointless to anyway because `Object.getPrototypeOf(o)` is the same thing as `o.__proto__` which is implemented in every browser aside from IE and can't (currently) be turned off. That means the only browsers that removing `Object.getPrototypeOf` from would have any effect on are IE9 and IE10.

The reason I figured he'd give is that some of those functions are mostly intended for use by "library author" type usages. This is something commonly believed/said by people involved with the specification process and I believe it is a legitimate claim; property descriptors/attributes and other "meta" level API's are more advanced features that can be cumbersome to use and generally require more complete language mastery to use correctly. However, this still wouldn't amount to a blanket recommendation of "don't use them". This more accurate claim wasn't even the argument he made, though.

One extra note about the video, in which he made a incorrect statement. He said property attributes (enumerable, configurable, writable) were *unchangeable* once set. This is incorrect. These can be changed so long as `configurable` is true. Once it is set to false the attributes become frozen (nor is the property deletable).

---

#### Edit: After having done research, I found some of the original discussions regarding this feature and the other Object functions. The summary as I understand it follows.

There was concern about the security implications of being able to access the [[Prototype]] of an object. However, these concerns were more fully and appropriately addressed via things like Object.freeze, and is also partly addressed (and a reason) that these functions live on Object as static functions (deletable in one location) instead of on Object.prototype or magically on every object like **proto** historically has been.

Another concern raised was of breaking encapsulation

> It's true that **proto** or getPrototypeOf breaks an object's encapsulation barrier and reveals implementation details that perhaps were intended to be hidden.  The same could be said about the proposed getProperty function which, among other things,  gives an observer access to the functions that implement a getter/setter property. In general, that's the nature of reflection. *-Allen Wirfs-Brock*

One concern raised from the implementation end was about exposing implementation details (mostly a concern stemming from how the DOM works which has since been addressed by changes to the DOM's use of multiple inheritance and the transition to WebIDL).

> On the other hand, providing reflective access to an object's prototype is harmful to compatibility because it prevents implementations from introducing intermediate prototypes without breaking the web.  Consider the example of having just Numbers and later compatibly introducing more specific subkinds of Numbers. -*Waldemar Horwat*

This concern is also related to another one mentioned on the script coordination mailing list about internal hidden prototypes being the same cross-frame. This issue is also historical as of ES5 (and IE8) where it was decided and implemented that each frame must instantiate its own set of DOM prototypes. Thus hiding of prototypes for this reason was no longer relevant by the time ES5 was formally published.

---

The consensus I see doesn't follow Crockford's explanation. Mostly it seems to just be the restatement of his own opinion.

> In summary, not providing reflective access to an object's prototype doesn't really provide any real security, it just makes  some useful tasks less convenient.
>   *-Allen Wirfs-Brock*
>
> ---
>
> I agree with you here in general, and it's good to hear that reflection is not the enemy of "real security".
>   *-Brendan Eich*

The starting point for this is [Proposed ECMAScript 3.1 Static Object Functions: Use Cases and Rationale](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=es3.1:es3.1_proposal_working_draft&cache=cache&media=es3.1:rationale_for_es3_1_static_object_methods.pdf) (written by Crockford and others on TC39). The followup to that, where I draw quotations from, is [this es-discuss thread](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-July/006664.html). Specifically [this post](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-July/006670.html) and [this post](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-July/006674.html).

Comment: Nice answer. Your second paragraph is very relevant, I think... maybe worth adding that if you're not writing library-level code, you should be able to maintain handles to prototypes yourself, or make sure they are available as properties of constructors... you really shouldn't need `getPrototypeOf` in self-contained, non-library code.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. That's what I wanted to hear, because as a library developer I'd definitely like to be free to use `getPrototypeOf`. I hope you don't mind me holding off a couple days on accepting the answer / rewarding the bounty, as I'd really be interested in knowing if there are any references to thoughts from anyone in the ES committee to either corroborate or debunk Crockford's statement. However, I fully intend to accept + reward the bounty to you if nothing more concrete comes forth. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I looked around your code because I was wondering how you were going to pull off `WeakMap`, and I found your solution quite elegant -- overriding `getOwnPropertyNames` to hide a secret property on each object. New trick to me. Nice work.

Comment: Thanks! GetOwnPropertyNames has few uses outside of library building and meta programming, so reducing its efficiency slightly is a small price to gain the benefits Collections provide. In regards to your other comment, I'll see if I can flesh out the answer with some primary references later today.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have awarded you the bounty. I want to keep the question open, however, in the hopes that someone will come around with some more definitive, referenced answers. I may try offering another bounty on it once I get a few more reputation points to give away. Cheers!

Comment: I had forgotten to finish writing up my findings and post them! The post has been edited with the information you desire.

Comment: Glad you linked to that thread, which is the first time I've seen Caja used as a specific justification for `getPrototypeOf`. (Incidentally, I wonder if Douglas would mind if someone, well, just asked? He seems like a nice enough guy, and his email address is publicly available from [his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford).)